# CodeIgniter pagination url page number

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

From what I saw, CodeIgniter's pagination is counting the page wrong way, because I got pagination looking like this:

> **1** 2 3 >

And its good, the problem is in the each pagination number url, except the first one:

Number **2** from the pagination has the following url:

> http://my-url.com/index.php/page/**1**

And number **3** has the following url:

> http://my-url.com/index.php/page/**2**

So, the number is URL is decreased by 1 everytime.

How can I solve that, so the page numbers in urls will be the same as the page numbers in the pagination?

My pagination config:

```
$config['per_page']    = 5;
$config['base_url']    = site_url('page');
$config['uri_segment'] = 2;
$page = $this->uri->segment(2);
$total_rows_array = $this->records->get($config['per_page'], $page * $config['per_page']); // parameters: limit, offset.
$config['total_rows']  = count($total_rows_array);
```

Answer (score 15):

Had the same problem you have, and I added this configuration line:

```
$config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
```

and **it works like a charm!**

Comment: i added additional code to make the above work like what @Dale had mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

Are you using page numbers in the pagination config?

The way CodeIgniters pagination works (by default) is that you set the number of records to show in the code, CodeIgniter works out the offset and appends that to the URL.

The reason page 1 (if you will) has no number at the end is because there is no offset, page 2 will have an offset of 1 because it is offsetting that many records. Wow this is a lot harder to explain than I thought before I started typing this answer!

:EDIT:

Also, if you are using page numbers in the pagination config, I imagine that code igniter is taking the per_page amount and multiplying it by the page number to get the real offset for the records.

Page 2 would really work out as per_page (15) * page_number (1) = 15 for the real offset.

Comment: It seems like I have everything done correctly, from what you said. I updated my answer with the config code.

Comment: Sorry I should explain that this is the way codeigniter works, I think if you really really wanted to have it display the 'correct' page number it would require some form of hack to ci's pagination class.

Comment: Also I'm not sure about this.. $config['uri_segment'] = $this->uri->segment(2);
I think what this is doing is actually setting the uri_segment to the value of $this->uri->segment(2), which could be 40987 and that wouldn't work :)

Comment: yeah I've noticed and fixed the `$config['uri_segment']` to the right one. Now I got an issue, so if I'm on null page (first one), the pagination doesn't work, it is showing 50 out of 50 records at one page instead of 5 records per page... Could you help with that?

Comment: I'm getting the records with the following limit: `$config['per_page'], $page * $config['per_page']` -> (LIMIT, OFFSET), see my updated answer.

Comment: presumably your page method accepts the page number as an argument, function page($page), you could do this I believe: function page($page = 0) which will automatically give it a zero value when it isn't passed in the url

Comment: for the uri-<segment(2) problem i use my own get_page_number funciton which will use regex to get the pagenumber which ever segment it is in... like check for /page/(*.?)/ ... (you can use your own regex)... i made sure that no uri segment other than that uses the word page... and all my urls are clean...

Comment: how to remove page from the uri segment of pagination with it is like this... /module/page/ ... because /module/ will have the same listing as /module/page/ which becomes duplicate content issue in seo. so fir the link number 1 it should be /module/ instead of /module/page/ ... other urls are fine like /module/page/2/ were as for the first page it should be without the word page... how to do that... there should be a simple gimmick instead of doing round trips. ?